# SQL table with subtotal

Tags: sql, subtotal

I am new to this SQL thing. I have a table like follows:

```
Table dataTable

caseID  Title   staffID  staffName  Date        Budget  Actual
------  ------  -------  ---------  ----------  ------  ------
413     Week 1  1213     Jackson    1990-10-07  1000    1000
413     Week 1  1214     Jeckson    1990-10-07  2000    1500
413     Week 2  1215     Jickson    1990-10-07  1000    1500 
414     Week 2  1216     Jockson    1990-10-08  1500    1000 
414     Week 2  1217     Juckson    1990-10-08  2000    1000
```

I want the result as follows;

to show every detail in the table, but also show total budget and total actual **group by caseID**

```
caseID  staffID  staffName  Date        Budget  Actual  totalBudget  totalActual
------  -------  ---------  ----------  ------  ------  -----------  -----------
413     1213     Jackson    1990-10-07  1000    1000
413     1214     Jeckson    1990-10-07  2000    1500
413     1215     Jickson    1990-10-07  1000    1500    4,000        2,500
414     1216     Jockson    1990-10-08  1500    1000 
414     1217     Juckson    1990-10-08  2000    1000    3,500        1,000
```

Could anyone help me with the code? I am unable to do it.

ps: I am really sorry I don't know how to show all these information in the table.

Comment: some engines support LEAD and LAG functions which could help you here. (OR - use a report writer)

Comment: I just found a solution, but the the subtotal that I came up with came like 4000 and 2500 instead of 4,000 and 2,500.. Could someone tell me how to convert them into this format? thank you very much.

Comment: Have a look at the [`FORMAT()` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_format), although I can't really see why you would want to format `totalBudget` and `totalActual` but return `Budget` and `Actual` unformatted.

Comment: Reporting tools are for formatting data; SQL is for selecting it.  If your reporting tools can't format the data, get better reporting tools.

Comment: andriy - Thank you very much and thank you everyone for all the responses.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
select
  t1.caseID, t1.staffID, t1.staffName, t1.Date, t1.Budget, t1.Actual, 
  format(t2.totalBudget, 0) TotalBudget, format(t2.totalActual, 0) TotalActual
from t t1 left join (
  select caseID, max(staffId) staffId, sum(Budget) totalBudget,
  sum(Actual) totalActual from t
  group by caseID
) t2 on t1.caseID = t2.caseID and t1.staffId = t2.staffId
```

The result is:

```
+--------+---------+-----------+------------+--------+--------+-------------+-------------+
| CASEID | STAFFID | STAFFNAME |    DATE    | BUDGET | ACTUAL | TOTALBUDGET | TOTALACTUAL |
+--------+---------+-----------+------------+--------+--------+-------------+-------------+
|    413 |    1213 | Jackson   | 07-10-1990 |   1000 |   1000 |             |             |
|    413 |    1214 | Jeckson   | 07-10-1990 |   2000 |   1500 |             |             |
|    413 |    1215 | Jickson   | 07-10-1990 |   1000 |   1500 |       4,000 |       4,000 |
|    414 |    1216 | Jockson   | 08-10-1990 |   1500 |   1000 |             |             |
|    414 |    1217 | Juckson   | 08-10-1990 |   2000 |   1000 |       3,500 |       2,000 |
+--------+---------+-----------+------------+--------+--------+-------------+-------------+
```

Let me know if you have any issue.

PS: Note your total actuals are wrong. You should update your question

Answer (score 0):

There are database-specific extensions to SQL (like [ROLLUP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189305%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) in t-sql) that could help with this but since you have not provided enough information on the platform you're running on here's a straight SQL solution that will work as long as your platform supports nested (derived) tables.

There does not seem to be any logic to placing the total lines at that point within the results according to your example so I've simply added the relevant results to every row.

```
SELECT a.caseID, a.staffID, a.staffName, a.Date, a.Budget, a.Actual, 
  b.totalBudget, b.totalActual
FROM tbl a INNER JOIN (
  SELECT caseID, SUM(Budget) as totalBudget, SUM(Actual) as totalActual
  FROM tbl 
  GROUP BY caseID
) b ON a.caseID = b.caseID
```

Comment: hi, thank you for your reply. For the code above, it shows the "totalbudget" and " totalactual " in every line. I would like it to show only on the last row of the caseid. In this case, only shows on 413 1215 and 414 1217 rows. Is it possible?

Comment: my dad wants to show the total budget and total actual cost for each case and he doesn't want the total to show every single line because it makes his eyes a little bit dizzy.